# finding and replacing duplicates in java

Tags: java

So, I am a newbie in java.

I have a arraylist of Strings.. So.. this array looks like:

```
[ "foo 123", "bar 124", "foobar 124","foo 125"]
```

What I want is to remove `foo 123`..

Why..

because foo is repeated twice.. and I want to keep the one with the largest count (next to the key)..

My approach has been bit convoluted..

Maintaining a hashmap with key and count. if key is present.. check the value and if value is greater then replace the entry??

I feel like this a clunky way to solve this.. 
Is there a good way to basically dedupe this list?
Thanks

Comment: good way to do what exactly ? The flow using HashMaps or you want an alternative to that ?

Comment: @Adarsh: oops.. rephrased the question :)

Comment: Why is the map clunky? Seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: The map option is good enough for this scenario.

Comment: how is foo 123 duplicated in the example, is foo 125 considered a duplicate.

Comment: @Tinman The duplicates are based on the first part of the string(before the space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is very simple - indeed, it's the fastest one asymptotically that you could have, because it is `O(N)` in both time and space.

The implementation is very straightforward, too. Use `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the insertion order of your keys.

```
String[] data = new String[] {"foo 123", "bar 124", "foobar 124","foo 125"};
Map<String,Integer> counts = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>();
for (String s : data) {
    String[] tok = s.split(" ");
    Integer count = Integer.valueOf(tok[1]);
    if (!counts.containsKey(tok[0]) || counts.get(tok[0]) < count) {
        counts.put(tok[0], count);
    }
}
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> e : counts.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " +e.getValue());
}
```

[Demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/sdpRpq).